# failed to allocate memory <NoMemoryError>

Tags: ruby, excel, file, csv, out-of-memory

I am trying to add an array of values I retrieve from an excel sheet, which is a 2D array [[row1contents],[row2contents],...]. I want to append each of these rows to a CSV file, and I have code that works for some cases but, in others I get the "Failed to allocate memory error". It says its a problem that starts with .join method

>

```
  #the location of the csv that I want to append to
  csv_filepath = regression_folder + '/Regression.csv'

  #out_book is the name of the workbook where I get the data to append from
  @out_book.calculate

  # Grab output sheet with data from workbook
  # OUTPUT_DATA_SHEET is name of the sheet in the workbook, sheet is a method written to 
  # retrieve a sheet
  output_sheet = @out_book.sheet(OUTPUT_DATA_SHEET)

  #puts "check if out_sheet empty"
  if @out_sheet.is_empty
    @out_sheet.createTable(output_sheet)
  end

  # read_range is method that reads in information from the sheet as 2D array listed above
  source = output_sheet.read_range(DEST_TABLE)

  # this is code to append 2D array to csv 
  File.open(csv_filepath,'a'){ |f| f << source.map(&:to_csv).join; nil } 

  puts "Total memory usage: #{ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all/1000.0} KB"
```

However, after all this, I get an error message that says
>

```
  main.rb:217:in 'join': failed to allocate memory <NoMemoryError>
          from main.rb:217:in 'block in initialize'
          from main.rb:217:in 'open'
          from main.rb:217:in 'initialize'
          from main.rb:471:in 'new'
          from main.rb:471:in '<main>'
```

Line 217 is the File.open(csv_filepath, 'a')... line and Line 471 is just where the main gets initialized.

Could anyone help me??

Comment: How much memory do you have available? How big is this file? Doing `source.map(...).join` creates the entire thing in memory which could be painfully expensive. Also what's that `nil` doing at the end? `File.open` doesn't care what you return.